# Send a message to a machine that is powered off

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003, sendmessage

I would like to send a message, or something can be an advise from a pc to an another pc (only one, or at the most 2), the latter is powered off.
The pc which should send the message is a windows server 2003 os, instead the pc which should receive the message is a windows xp os.

The two machines are in the same domain and they work together through an ingres database.

The message will be sent at night, because there is an ingres database back up procedure that runs at night when my pc will be powered off, but when in the morning i will be at work I would like to read this message as a net send message, or something like

Unfortunately the net send command is disabled in our network, so I can't use it, but i'm looking a way for sending this message.

Have you any suggestion? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use age-old simple file based messaging.

Store a message in a specific file in the server and write a simple application which runs on startup on your machine to read it and display it.

And this is apart from rerun's great suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

There is breaking new technology available called email.

Comment: That's as helpful as "switch to Linux" or "buy new hardware".

Comment: Actuality it is an appropriate solution.  He could easily add a command at the end of the database backup to send an email.  He was seeking a way to get some type of information for the process.  Net send is not an option and WOL is unreliable.  Email is a valid tool for this task supported everywhere and easily accessed.

Comment: Very funny, but the two machine have not mail service :))

Comment: well, there i a sort of, is called microsoft outlook web access, but for using it it is the same as going to the server machine and look at if the back up procedure has been executed correctly. Fine anyway, there are some suggestions.

Comment: You don't need a mail service as long as there is any mail server on the network that will allow smtp.  And you can read email.

Comment: thankyou, I don't have really understood what you wrote, but it sounds good

Comment: If you have a mail server on your network.  And you have access to port 25 you can send email.

Answer (score 1):

Is the machine powered off or in standby?

If if is in standby, then I will defer to someone who may have a better idea of how to get wake the machine to wake up programatically(sp?).

If it is powered off then read on...

If you have access to the machines bios settings, then I would suggest scheduling a power on event in the range of the time before the backup normally completes.

Then it is a matter of receiving the message and optionally shutting back down afterward?

If you are unable to change the bios settings, then does the machine "power on after power loss?"  If so, get a programmable timer from the nearest retail store and power off before leaving at night and have the timer set to power on before the time the backup could reasonably be completed.

This is not really a software solution per se, but your problem does seem to be mostly hardware related (with the power off requirement and all...)

Comment: it sounds very well what you wrote. But today, i don't really feel to go deeply. I use the solution suggested by user483269,  thankyou